# can't split terminal using screen

Tags: gnome3, kali-linux, gnome-terminal

- OS: Kali Linux version 1.1.0
- gnome version 3.4.2

---

Using screen, I press CTRL + a and | but nothing is being split. Only the words "No other window" appears in the bottom.

Here is other things I tried

> - CTRL + a and capital S
> - CTRL + a and b
> - CTRL + a and c
> - CTRL + a and | *(Pipe key)*

none of the above fixed it for me

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it's worth to mention that by detaching the screen,  splits won't persist. You need to create the split each time you enter the screen session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, in sequence:

```
CTRL+a, | # create a new pane
CTRL+a, <TAB> # goto the new pane
CTRL+a, c # start a new shell in the pane
```